# What Packages/How Do I Uninstall Propriety AMD Catalyst Driver

Tags: ati, proprietary, catalyst

How do I go back to the open source driver?

I installed AMD driver following on screen instructions but have a little shaded square in bottom right hand corner that says "AMD Unsupported hardware".

The Linux PDF says to use native package manager to uninstall driver, but I need to know what it is called to locate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the correct way to remove the ATI drivers:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

*Note: ignore any errors you may have got form running the first 2 commands.*

Remove your xorg.conf file

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Re-install xorg

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
```

Configure xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Source form [Install ATI official drivers in Ubuntu](http://ubuntutechnical.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/install-ati-official-drivers-in-ubuntu/)