# How to install a program ending in ".run" using terminal

Tags: installation, command-line, ati, radeon

I am following [How to Install AMD ATI Radeon Graphics HD 6770M](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285609/how-to-install-amd-ati-radeon-graphics-hd-6770m-on-ubuntu-13-04-64bit/285615#285615)

but at step no 5. i don't know how to do it 
5 - Install Catalyst driver, type the following commands on terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads 
chmod +x amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run
sudo sh amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run
```

this file in the downloads spot how can i use this command to install it

because i can't run it as execute as program

Comment: I would advice sticking to the additional drivers tab in software sources, Ubuntu Software Center and files ending on .DEB. .RUN files might be a bit too much if you are not comfy with terminal commands ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press the super key and search for terminal...

[image]

and activate it ...

Now type or copy/paste these lines one by one (so pressing enter after each line):

```
cd ~/Downloads 
chmod +x amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run
sudo sh amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run
```

the 1st 2 commands will show nothing when executed. The last one will ask for your admin password and then show a lot of lines. Watch out for errors :)

Comment: Thanks bro your answer work BUT TO BAD :( LOW GRAPICH CARD ERROR SO I Removed it :(

Comment: if that has not been solved on AU make a new question ;) Good luck Omar

Answer (score 0):

Where does your webbrowser store downloaded files?
When using your webbrowser, did you download the run-file in your Downloads folder?

Or is the downloaded file elsewhere? Use the Files program to put the downloaded file in your Downloads folder.

Comment: he already said it is in "the downloads spot". I took the liberty  to assume he means ~/Downloads ;)