# Matrox M9128 Driver Install

Tags: matrox

Matrox drivers will not install in Ubuntu 12.04 matrox does not offer help.
Anyone have this issue, solutions?

Answer (score 0):

First download either the [32bit](http://ubuntuone.com/6dYS1ljJVjova8l94yH9hY) or [64bit](http://ubuntuone.com/16JEWNpCWin9LXWpjBtJtf) driver, both have a release date of Dec. 16, 2013.  The files are .run files.  To install see [How to install a program ending in “.run” using terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286491/how-to-install-a-program-ending-in-run-using-terminal) **or** [How do I install .run files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18747/how-do-i-install-run-files).  For other information, and installation requirements, see the [Readme](ftp://ftp.matrox.com/pub/mga/archive/linux/2013/1.4.2/README.txt) file.