# How to install AMD graphics divers on hybrid system with intel onboard graphic card?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, intel-graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC, but without 2 AMD graphics card on PCIe.
So I am using PC with Intel graphics card which is on board so far.

But I bought 2 AMD graphics card HD7970. But for computing purpose not for connecting and expanding monitors but really only for parallel computing. So it means that I want to stay on Intel gr, was that there is some xorg.conf and needs to be edited. But I think in my case it hasn't. Because I have no monitors to connect to this 2 AMD graphics card. Am I right?
If there is answer to this question please direct me. If not I will be very gratefull for answer. And sorry for my english I am not the native speaker.
Thank you in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you read this article. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD
 or [How to Install AMD ATI Radeon Graphics HD 6770M](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285609/how-to-install-amd-ati-radeon-graphics-hd-6770m-on-ubuntu-13-04-64bit)