# Unity stopped working after update

Tags: unity, unity-2d

After I updated my 12.04.3 installation yesterday normal Unity didnt show up.
It keeps falling back to Unity2D.

Also `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` says my graphic card AMD Radeon HD 6700 Series  is not supported but is used to work for over a year. It maybe that some recent changes to unity package broke something.

Update history:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6727763/

I have tried doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

But now LightDM ist even starting.
How to repair it to usable state?

Comment: Have you tried installing some drivers for your graphics card?

Comment: I have the newest AMD drivers installed before it happen.

Comment: Well make sure it is still installed. Somehow I doubt it will be.

Comment: thanks Tim! removing with force option worked! I followed this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/160605/what-packages-how-do-i-uninstall-propriety-amd-catalyst-driver is it safe install AMD drivers again? (I play games on that machine so I need fancy graphic.. [yes! native games! thx Valve])

Answer (score 2):

Solution was easy:
This will remove proprietary driver and install Open Source one.

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Remove your xorg.conf file

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Re-install xorg

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
```

Configure xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Now you can install proprietary driver again.
Cheers!

Comment: This will switch from proprietary drivers to open source ones, maybe it would be useful to comment it. Moreover (I have a similar configuration) I had to add `radeon.dpm=1` to kernel boot parameters to avoid serious overheating, see http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395

Comment: Interesting because I'm using this stack for over 1 year and half with 12.04 and I haven't seen abnormally high temperature.